# How to set TabLayout background to transparent

Tags: android, tabs

I need to change TabLayout (extending HorizontalScrollView) background to transparent without changing primary color from styles. 
If I set a background to #00000000 it becomes primaryColor. If I set alpha to 0 - I get the same behavior.

[image]

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#00000000"
        android:hapticFeedbackEnabled="true"/>
```

Is there any way to set background color transparent without changing styles colors?

Comment: Try to set this on background @android:color/transparent

Comment: It's links to <color name="transparent">#00000000</color>
The same color as my in xml file.

Comment: put full xml layout @onCreate

Comment: `If I set a background to #00000000 it becomes primaryColor.` **NO**. It's transparent (meaning **invisible**). As such, you **see through** it. Therefore you see the parent's ... background color.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  I'm running into this.  Setting a global background color in styles.xml seems to override any background you set on the `TabLayout`

Answer (score 12):

Use:

```
 android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```

also in the AppBarLayout.
to remove the shadow to make look better you can remove the elevation of the AppBarlayout with:

```
 app:elevation="0dp"
```

Answer (score 5):

If you are using `<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout />`, you have to insert your TabLayout outside of it.

```
<!-- App Bar -->
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/app_bar"
            ......
            android:background="@color/app_bar_color"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<!-- Tab Layout -->
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
       android:id="@+id/tabs"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:background="@android:color/transparent"
       android:hapticFeedbackEnabled="true"/>
```

[The Result will be like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ejqa6.png)

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:alpha="0.3"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    android:hapticFeedbackEnabled="true"/>
```

it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Code in Kotlin

First of all, we will create CustomTabLayout

```
import android.content.Context
import android.graphics.Color
import android.util.AttributeSet
import com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout

class CustomTabLayout : TabLayout {
    constructor(context: Context) : super(context)
    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?) : super(context, attrs)
    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?, defStyleAttr: Int) : super(
        context,
        attrs,
        defStyleAttr
    )

    override fun onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec: Int, heightMeasureSpec: Int) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec)
        setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT)
    }
}
```

Then we will use it directly in the layout file

```
<com.packagename.CustomTabLayout
                        android:id="@+id/tab"
                        app:tabInlineLabel="true"
                        app:tabIndicator="@null"
                        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginHorizontal="16dp"
                        app:tabBackground="@null"
                        android:hapticFeedbackEnabled="true"
                        app:tabIndicatorHeight="0dp"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        tools:layout_height="40dp" />
```

And it will work tab layout with transparent background
Let me know if you need anything else regarding this question.