# Android Toolbar overlapping TabLayout in CollapsingToolbarLayout

Tags: android, android-toolbar, overlapping, android-coordinatorlayout, android-tablayout

I'm trying to make `CollapsingToolbarLayout` with `Toolbar` and `TabLayout` below it, but they overlapping each other and I get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/09HyL.png)

[image]

I've tried many solutions, but still have this problem. Here is my xml:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="@color/colorAppPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/image"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="250dp"
                android:background="@drawable/material_plane"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/header_png"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|enterAlwaysCollapsed">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageViewPhoto"
                    android:layout_width="80dp"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textViewName"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/imageViewPhoto"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:text="TEXT"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="16dp" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:gravity="top"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="20dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:tabBackground="@android:color/transparent"
                app:tabMode="scrollable" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to remove this from your `RelativeLayout`:

```
app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|enterAlwaysCollapsed">
```

Or just let them be like this:

```
app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlwaysCollapsed">
```

It was a bug i guess.

---

**UPDATED:** check this link: http://blog.grafixartist.com/parallax-scrolling-tabs-design-support-library/

And similar question: [How to use a TabLayout with Toolbar inside CollapsingToolbarLayout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30680824/how-to-use-a-tablayout-with-toolbar-inside-collapsingtoolbarlayout)

```
<android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:background="@drawable/header"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageViewPhoto"
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
                android:layout_below="@+id/imageViewPhoto"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:text="TEXT"
                android:textSize="16dp" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:gravity="top"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/htab_tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
```

Comment: I tried this, but then my `CollapsingToolbarLayout` become higher and I can't put `TabLayout` inside. (I need transparent `TabLayout`)

Comment: Do you want something like this example? : https://github.com/TheLittleNaruto/SupportDesignExample i just updated the answer.

Comment: So, the answer is correct, you should put that `TabLayout` under `CollapsingToolbarLayout`.and if you want it transparent, you can check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32372391/how-to-set-tablayout-background-to-transparent or - `android:background="@android:color/transparent"` that's the another issue btw.

Comment: Ok. I have transparent `TabLayout`, but how can I put it higher (at the bottom of `RelativeLayout`)? I tried margin, but then I have overlapping again.

Comment: That's why i said you need to put it under the `CollapsingToolbarLayout` check this layout: https://github.com/TheLittleNaruto/SupportDesignExample/blob/master/app/src/main/res/layout/app_container_view.xml

Comment: Now my `TabLayout` is under `RelativeLayout`, but not inside

Comment: So, what is the problem? did it collapsed perfectly?

Comment: Let me show you. [Screenshot](http://higgs.rghost.ru/6FF7nV5Lj/image.png). Red arrow shows `TabLayout` position and green arrow shows position where I want to locate it.

Comment: Still got overlapping :(

Comment: That link should do what you are looking for, perhaps you missed something.

Comment: I set Toolbar height to (toolbar_height+tabllayout_height) and now it's look great! Thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 2):

I also got into similar kind of problem, i tried removing `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` from `CoordinatorLayout.` And it worked.

Answer (score 2):

I found a way to resolve the using just add this line in  toolbar layout.

```
android:layout_marginBottom="48dp"
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit your XML like this:

```
 <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:tabBackground="@android:color/transparent"
            app:tabMode="scrollable"/>
```

Comment if it does not work

Answer (score 0):

You have to keep your TabLayout below the CollapsingToolbarLayout, and it will be working sure, you can see my code from below:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleMarginBottom="@dimen/_32sdp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="@dimen/_64sdp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="@dimen/_48sdp"
        app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|enterAlwaysCollapsed">

        <!--  Your View that you want to hide on animation -->
        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_250sdp"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

        <!-- Your toolbar should always below your View otherwise it won't be visible  -->
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolBar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
            app:title="title text"
            app:titleTextColor="@color/white" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    <!--your tablayout should be here which will come below the toolbar-->
    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_50sdp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="@color/theme_color"
        android:overScrollMode="never"
        android:scrollbars="horizontal"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/appbar"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/orrange"
        app:tabMode="scrollable" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <include layout="@layout/content" />

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

All the best.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you are using the following structure:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout> 
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
<android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
<ImageView />
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar />
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout />
</android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

In which you need to make sure that only toolbar has:

```
android:layout_marginBottom="48dp"
app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
```

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
      android:id="@+id/toolbar"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
      android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
      app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
      android:layout_gravity="top"
      android:layout_marginBottom="48dp"
      app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
      >
```

And `CollapsingToolbarLayout` Must contain

```
app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|snap"
```

```
<android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|snap"
app:titleEnabled="false">
```