# How to set TabLayout transparent keeping my icons and text white

Tags: android, xml, layout, android-tablayout, android-appbarlayout

This is my very first question here but I´ve researched a lot before.
So I´m new with Android development and am trying to design a custom login/signing activity based on new ViewPager and TabLayouts.
The thing is that i´m trying to set a transparency background to my two tabs AppBarLayout and can´t find anything that works well for me.
I´ve tried lots of posted solutions and no one seems to fit my case.
Last one is this posted here:

[How to set TabLayout background to transparent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32372391/how-to-set-tablayout-background-to-transparent)

but nothing, the better i can get is something like this:
[transparent background try](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D1imM.png)

Here is the layout code that gets this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_gravity="left|center_horizontal"
        android:background="#f2a0ef"
        android:contentDescription="@string/logDesc" />

    <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="340dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="top|center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="-102dp"
        android:theme="@style/MyMaterialTheme"
        android:layout_marginBottom="80dp"
        android:transitionGroup="false">


        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent">

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/custom_tab_layout_height"
                app:tabMode="fixed"
                app:tabGravity="fill"
                app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                app:tabIndicatorHeight="4dp"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                />
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>



        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewpager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="false"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
            android:layout_below="@+id/appBarLayout"
            android:background="#ffffff" />

</RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I think activity code is not needed, if so, tell me please.
the thing is that i´ve almost get it but that effect surrounding the tabs is not desired of course.
I´m really stuck with this and don´t want to keep doing things before i get this done.
Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

Use TabLayout outside AppBarLayout

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"

        >
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/custom_tab_layout_height"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:tabIndicatorHeight="4dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            />
```

Answer (score 0):

I´m sooo stupid, that weird behave comes from the dropping shadow of the appBarLAyout widget if set above anything, because setting transparency to the tabs makes it drop a weird shadow, so 2 days trying the impossibe to make it work and the only thing a had to do is setting the elevation of the widget to "0dp".

this is the final code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_gravity="left|center_horizontal"
        android:background="#f2a0ef"
        android:contentDescription="@string/logDesc" />

    <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="340dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="top|center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="-102dp"
        android:theme="@style/MyMaterialTheme"
        android:layout_marginBottom="80dp"
        android:transitionGroup="false">


        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            **app:elevation="0dp"**


            >

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/custom_tab_layout_height"
                app:tabMode="fixed"
                app:tabGravity="fill"
                app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                app:tabIndicatorHeight="4dp"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                />
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>



        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewpager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="false"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
            android:layout_below="@+id/appBarLayout"
            android:background="#ffffff" />

</RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

and the final result (the one i desired):

[final result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gwryh.png)

Thanks!!!