# TabLayout transparency

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-tablayout

I'm creating an app currently and this issue occurred, I want to make `TabLayout` transparent. When I use `RelativeLayout` `TabLayout` covers content, when I use `LinearLayout` `TabLayout` background becomes not transparent anymore. How could I solve?
There are some images and code:
[image: RealitiveLayout]
[image: LinearLayout]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.android.news.MainActivity"
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="#67000000"
    app:tabTextColor="#ffffff"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/colorAccent"
    app:tabMode="fixed" />
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Have a look :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32372391/how-to-set-tablayout-background-to-transparent/70261969#70261969

Answer (score 1):

Set background to tab layouts `android:background="@android:color/transparent"`

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
   android:id="@+id/tabs"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:background="@android:color/transparent"
   android:hapticFeedbackEnabled="true"/>
```

or you can give custom background slightly transparent colour

```
1) 90% - 90 e.g android:background="#90000000"
2) 80% - 90 e.g android:background="#80000000"
3) 70% - 70 e.g android:background="#70000000"
```

Comment: Yea, I have done this in the first pic, but then it covers content when it's scrolled at the top.